# How to downgrade rails version in Max OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Mac OS X Snow leopard that has pre-installed Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.1
I need to work with Redmine a bit that requires Rails 2.3.5

Is it possible to correctly downgrade my current rails 3.0.1 to rails 2.3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to downgrade, RubyGems allow you to install multiple versions of the same library.

```
$ gem install rails -v 2.3.5
```

Comment: Is it any way to set a 'current version', so my rails commands refer to 2.3.5, not 3.0.1? (for example, rails -v shows 3.0.1 after installing 2.3.5)

Comment: No, you need to remove 3.0.1 or use `rails _2.3.5_ COMMAND` instead of `rails COMMAND`

Comment: Sorry for being nub in gems - how to correctly remove 3.0.1 ?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid versioning hell, you can also use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), which allows you to install multiple ruby versions and "gemsets" on the same machine and switch between them.